# How to speed up GitHub pull/fetch with my Wifi router?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, github

I've a 50MBPS internet connection. Everthing is pretty fast except GitHub requests. If I connect via my mobile phones hotspot, it goes pretty fast. What could be the reason for this slowness? I don't have any QOS settings done in the router. Here are the details -

DDRT Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (05/27/13) mini
Model: Linksys E900 Wireless-N300 Router

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you’re using Git over SSH, it’s just regular HTTPS traffic. Is browsing on GitHub also slow? Does it affect all repositories?

Comment: Is "50MBPS" 50 megabits per second (50,000,000 bits per second) or 50 MebiBytes per second (419,430,400 bits per second)? Also, can you quantify (measure) the slowness, and also quantify the "pretty fast" of the mobile hotspot case? It feels like you haven't given us enough information to help you. I second DanielB's implicit question of "What protocol are you using for 'GitHub requests'?" It might also be interesting to know what CDN nodes you're hitting via Wi-Fi vs. cellular.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, it does usually affect all repositories. My work repos are over SSH while many others I use via npm are over HTTPS. This difference in speed varies from 15KBps to 100KBps over WiFi but generally it is on the lower side. While on Mobile hotspot, it is in 200KBps to 1.5Mbps. The unit is Megabits per second. Thanks Spiff. Please let me know if you guys need more info.